# Jodconverter: Fails randomly when running tests with libreoffice (docker)

Tags: libreoffice, jodconverter

While running conversions in test suites using jodconverter, it was randomly crashing and tests failed.

We are using Libreoffice with jodconverter running tests in docker. Took too much time to figure this out, so created this question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : 
Use `-PuseLibreOffice` with the test command to signal jodconverter to use libs for libreoffice. Default is open office.
`./gradlew test -PuseLibreOffice`